# Do monsters always inflict bludgeoning damage to each other?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

As I acknowledge, monsters in *World* can flinch and even break part of others by their attack. Since monster attacks logically fall into "bludgeoning damage" because they slam each other for most of the time, I suspect they are always bludgeoning.

Well, are they? Glavenus, for example, has a *blade* at its tail, and Velkhana *pierces* with its sharp tail. Nergigante fires *spikes* from an impact point. Do they also count as bludgeoning, no exception? Is there a bullet damage among monsters? Are breath weapons by, for example, Rathalos, treated as bullet damage?

Also, is there a possibility that the subject damage is actually equivalent to *explosions*, like Gunlances, cluster ammo, or cannons?

Comment: *Are* falling boulders treated as bludgeoning damage?

Comment: Come to think of it, there was actually the fourth damage type which is neither sever, blunt nor bullet-explosion (fixed) damages...... Anyway, this makes the question grounded by an unsure hypothesis, so I will modify the question detail.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Interesting, and this led to another curiosity, which spawned [another question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362193/does-lance-still-inflict-piercing-damage).

Comment: Ah, so it appears World is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, Kiranico has somehow or another datamined attack values for each monster. They're in Japanese, but the tables look like [this](https://mhworld.kiranico.com/monsters/Rz9Tb/rathian) (scroll to the bottom):

[image]

Based on these values, it does appear that *most* Monster attacks deal KO damage. (Whether or not it makes sense to classify this as "Bludgeoning" damage is an exercise left up to the reader).

Further down the list you'll see Rathian's fireballs, which *don't* inflict stun. So the real answer is -- **only monster attacks that are programmed to inflict KO damage... inflict KO damage**, which doesn't seem particularly insightful! (But will make us honorary members of tautology club)

In particular, the Kulu-Ya-Ku's entry has `岩叩きつけ    40.00   80.00(KO)   0   40.00` which Google translate notes as "Rock Throwing" -- so there's the stun damage on the rock that you observed!

Comment: So, back to the original question, if I were to question whether monster attacks are bludgeoning, then I have to make Kulu break Barroth scalp......

Comment: @ArleCamille For what it's worth, KO damage does not imply blunt damage.

Comment: Exactly, Wrigglenite. (See punishing draw and/or impact mantle) @ArleCamille - my assumption (and the Occam's razor of things) is that monsters deal neither slashing nor blunt damage, just "damage".

Comment: Based on the "Occam's razor rule" @RavenDreamer mentioned, I will accept this answer for now, because it seems it is how the game works given how Impact Phials stun and Bombs do no type of damage. However, if there is ever a figure which says the contrary, I will happily accept that answer.