# Does Lance still inflict piercing damage?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

According to a comment in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362190/do-monsters-always-inflict-bludgeoning-damage-to-each-other), it is said that Lance actually inflicts a piercing damage i.e., itself is sever but the actual damage number depends on whether the target is weaker to sever or blunt, also in World. Is it correct?

If it is, how does the skill Weakness Exploit interact with a blunt weak spot that is strong against sever when using a Lance? Does it

- not register because I am using a sever weapon anyway? or,
- register because the true damage is based on blunt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Lance does not deal piercing damage in Monster Hunter World.

I picked Behemoth to test this, because of how different his hitzones are for the various types of damage. Behemoth's front legs have 50 and 40 hitzone values for sever and blunt respectively. His hind legs, on the other hand, have 30 and 55 hitzone values for sever and blunt.

If the Lance did piercing damage, it would deal more damage to Behemoth's hind legs than his front legs. Instead, the third upthrust dealt 57 damage on a crit to Behemoth's front legs, and 34 damage on a crit to Behemoth's hind legs. These numbers are consistent with the sever hitzone values, and the blunt hitzone values are completely ignored.

Comment: About a forecasted claim that “Lance piercing was actually not 1:1,” the point is that the empirical data was *completely* on par with sever hitzones (57:34 almost matches 50:30). If Lance were to have 72% of sever damage as its “bludgeoning” damage as in old installments, the damage number should have displayed something like 45.